# jsp : safe selection menu

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to the use of jsp's, servlets, beans etc ... .

Maybe a strange question, but what is the safest way to make a selection menu in a jsp, to make sure you can't access it directly.

At this moment I have a login system and depending of the "kind" of user I retrieve from the db I send them to a specific jsp depending on the "permissions" they have.  On this page they will get a selection of the possibilities they can do.

but if I use something like:

```
<a href="next.jsp">next option</a>
```

it would be easy to just access these next pages from the outside (not much use for the login system then).

I can use a bean I retrieve from the previous page that I check if it's null (this would be so if you get directly to this page) or something like that.

Any suggestions would be welcome.  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Servlet Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) to validate if the user has logged in the system and to verify if the user has the rights to access to this page. An example would be as stated in [StackOverflow Servlet-Filters wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). Posting the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    //session.getAttribute("user") contains the user info in session
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
    } else {
        // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        chain.doFilter(req, res); 
    }
}
```